# React Syntax Error: Unexpected Token at =

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

```
ERROR in ./src/js/HomeView.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (122:19)

  120 |   }
  121 | 
> 122 |   handleDrawerOpen = () => {
      |                    ^
  123 |     this.setState({ open: true });
  124 |   };
  125 |
```

Got the above error when trying to compile react component using webpack.
Does anyone know what is the missing plugin here?

Comment: Can I see the full source including that part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to install [preset-stage-2](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/).
This babel plugin allows you to use ES6+ features such as `static`s, `property initializers`, and even dynamic import support.
You could actually just install [transform-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) for this particular case, but I usually prefer to install a babel plugin with stage-x because I find it comfortable to use multiple ES6+ features with a single install.
It might also be useful to future readers that this particular Babel plugin is already properly set up for you if you use [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/), as you can check [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/2e82ebb3371731a5c4e346f310848ddb23fd0976/packages/babel-preset-react-app/index.js#L11).

Comment: Mind to explain why that is needed?

Comment: this is called `property initializers` and they are part of ES7 standard. to enable them in ES5/ES6 environments, you need to use a transpiler with proper settings. you can read more [here](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/es7-property-initializers)

Comment: @Mox I'm editing right now, sorry but I usually prefer to give a brief answer and then provide more details in the next hour or two.

Comment: Also, you'll find further infos in the link embedded into my answer

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to guess from the code you have pasted above.

My guess is change it to

```
handleDrawerOpen() {
    this.setState({ open: true });
}
```